# syntaxerror can't assign to function call in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am haveing Syntax error in following code in python can anyone help me with the solution? my code is given below

```
    **from operator import itemgetter
d = {"A":1,"b":2,"c":5,"d":4}
print("original dic \n" ,d)
sor = sorted(d.itemsec), key=itemgetter(0)
print("in ascending order : " ,sor) 
sor = sorted(d.itemsec), key=itemgetter(0), reverse=true
print("in reverse = " ,sor)
d.update({"v":7})
print("updated directery" ,d)
d1 = {"x":9}
d.update(d1)
print("concetinated dir = \n" ,d)
d2 = {"r":12, "s":14, "u":333}
d2.update(d)
print("merged dirs are = \n" )
print(d2)**
```

Comment: Your sorted function calls are wrong. You need to put the whole thing under sorted(). Example: sor=sorted(d.itemsec, key=itemgetter(0))

Comment: sor = sorted(d.itemsec, key=itemgetter(0))

Comment: Please paste the actual exception, not just the vague description "Syntax error". Python shows you where the error is.

Comment: But you have a ton of syntax errors and other errors here. There's an indent error and syntax error (that `**`) in the first line. Then, every `d.itemsec` is an attribute error—did you mean `items()` maybe? Then you put `key=itemgetter(0)` as a statement, but attached to an expression by a comma, which is illegal; you presumably wanted it to be a keyword argument inside the parens. And same again, and same for `reverse=true`. Then `true` is a name error; you probably meant `True`. You probably don't want a space after `'in reverse ='`, although that's not actually an error. And so on.

Comment: Also, what is this code supposed to _do_? For example, is there a reason you're writing `d1 = {"x": 9}` and then `d.update(d1)`? Do you expect that to do something different than just `d["x"] = 9`? If so, without knowing _what_ you expect it to do, it's impossible to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: To avoid downvoting, you should mention the error you got and your trials to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There are several errors in your code...

1. The `sorted` statement require the closing bracket to surround
   all its arguments.
2. Just put the dictionary without any other additions like `.items`, or the keyword you use.
3. The keyword True should be capitalized.

This is the working code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
d = {"A":1,"b":2,"c":5,"d":4}
print("original dic \n" ,d)
sor = sorted(d, key=itemgetter(0))
print("in ascending order : " ,sor) 
sor = sorted(d, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
print("in reverse = " ,sor)
d.update({"v":7})
print("updated directery" ,d)
d1 = {"x":9}
d.update(d1)
print("concetinated dir = \n" ,d)
d2 = {"r":12, "s":14, "u":333}
d2.update(d)
print("merged dirs are = \n" )
print(d2)
```

Best regards

Comment: Of course it's hard to be sure, but I doubt this is what he wants. He probably wants to sort the items, not the keys, of the dict.